# c# finding different words in two texts

Tags: c#, arrays

I need help.
I need to find  words, which are in text1, but not in text2,also count how many times they occur.

Example:

Text1(hello, world apple,pineapple,cabbage,apple)

Text2(hello, world,pineapple)

Result:

apple 2;

cabbage1;

Also it would be awesome to do it without List

Comment: Why does " world apple" contribute to the count of "apple"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text1 = "hello, world apple,pineapple,cabbage,apple";
string text2 = "hello, world,pineapple";

string pattern = @"\p{L}+";

var list1 = Regex.Matches(text1, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
var list2 = Regex.Matches(text2, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);


var result =   list1.Where(x => !list2.Contains(x))
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x =>new
                {
                    Word = x.Key,
                    Count= x.Count()
                })
                .ToList();
```

This will return

```
Word = apple,   Count = 2
Word = cabbage, Count = 1
```

Of course there is room for some performance improvements but it'll leave them out for clarity...

Answer (score 2):

you can use two array and then using `Group By` you can achieve your goal in this way:

```
    string[] text1 = new []{"hello", "world", "apple", "pineapple", "cabbage", "apple"};
    string[] text2 = new []{"apple", "pineapple", "cabbage", "apple"};

    string[] combinedText = text1.Concat(text2).ToArray();
    var groups = combinedText.GroupBy(v => v);

    foreach(var group in groups)
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0} has {1} items", group.Key, group.Count());
```

**Edit:**

it looks like you're wanting the solution in slightly different way, so i'm also showing that below:

```
    string[] text1 = new []{"hello", "world", "apple", "pineapple", "cabbage", "apple"};
    string[] text2 = new []{"apple", "pineapple", "cabbage", "apple"};

    var text1Groups = text1.GroupBy(v => v);
    var text2Groups = text2.GroupBy(v => v);

    foreach(var group in text1Groups)
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key.ToString() + group.Count().ToString());

    foreach(var group in text2Groups)
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key.ToString() + group.Count().ToString());
```

Comment: negative voter? why negative vote?