# C# using dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, text

I'm sorry in advance if it's bad to ask for this sort of help... but I don't know who else to ask.

I have an assignment to read two text files, and find the 10 longest words in the first file (and the amount of times they're repeated) which dont exist in the second file.

I currently read both of the files with File.ReadAllLines then split them into arrays, where every element is a single word (punctuation marks removed as well) and removed empty entries.

The idea I had to pick out the words fitting the requirements was: to make a dictionary containing a string Word and an int Count. Then make a loop repeating for the first file's length.... firstly comparing the element with the entire dictionary - if it finds a match, increase the Count by 1. Then if it doesn't match with any of the dictionary elements - compare the given element with every element in the 2nd file through another loop, if it finds a match - just go on to the next element of the first file, if it doesn't find any matches - add the word to the dictionary, and set Count to 1.

So my first question is: Is this actually the most efficient way to do this? (Don't forget I've only recently started studying c# and am not allowed to use linq)

Second question: How do I work with the dictionary, because most of the results I could find were very confusing, and we have not yet met them at university.

My code so far:

```
    // Reading and making all the words lowercase for comparisons
    string punctuation = " ,.?!;:\"\r\n";
    string Read1 = File.ReadAllText("@\\..\\Book1.txt");
    Read1 = Read1.ToLower();
    string Read2 = File.ReadAllText("@\\..\\Book2.txt");
    Read2 = Read2.ToLower();

    //Working with the 1st file
    string[] FirstFileWords = Read1.Split(punctuation.ToCharArray());

    var temp1 = new List<string>();
    foreach (var word in FirstFileWords)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
            temp1.Add(word);
    }
    FirstFileWords = temp1.ToArray();

    Array.Sort(FirstFileWords, (x, y) => y.Length.CompareTo(x.Length));

    //Working with the 2nd file
    string[] SecondFileWords = Read2.Split(punctuation.ToCharArray());

    var temp2 = new List<string>();
    foreach (var word in SecondFileWords)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
            temp2.Add(word);
    }
    SecondFileWords = temp2.ToArray();
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way?  No.  If `m` is the number of words in the first book and `n` is the number of words in the second book then by using a loop to compare (almost) every word in the first book to every word in the second book you are going to end up with a runtime on the order of something like O(mn).  This problem can be solved in O(m + n).

Comment: @JasonBoyd what about making it the loop run N times, and initially setting N to 10 (cause we need 10 words), and if the word matches either one in the dictionary or one in the 2nd file I increase N by 1, since the word isn't being used so we'll need to go one deeper into the array to find the 10 words?

Comment: seems like  your class mates are here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951825/c-sharp-finding-different-words-in-two-texts

Comment: `I'm sorry in advance if it's bad to ask for this sort of help...` I thought homeworks were assigned for you. If you want me to do it, of course I can... But would I want you as a co worker in the future? No?

Comment: @EZI I dont want someone to do it for me though, I want someone to point me in the right direction as to how to do this

Comment: @BligenN Why do you need direction? Read your books. I was also a computer science student in the times where no internet was there... You  have even Google..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think you've done very well so far. Not being able to use Linq here is torture ;)

As for performance, you should consider making your SecondFileWords a `HashSet<string>` as this would increase lookup times if any word exists in the 2nd file tremendously without much effort. I wouldn't go much further in terms of performance optimization for an exercise like that if performance is not a key requirement.

Of course, you would have to check that you don't add duplicates to your 2nd list, so change your current implementation to something like:

```
HashSet<string> temp2 = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var word in SecondFileWords)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word) && !temp2.Contains(word))
    {
        temp2.Add(word);
    }
}
```

Don't convert this back to an Array again, this is not necessary.

This brings me back to your FirstFileWords which would contain duplicates too. This will cause issues later on when the top words might contain the same word multiple times. So let's get rid of them. Here it's more complicated as you need to retain the information how often a word appeared in your first list.

So let's bring a `Dictionary<string, int>` into play here now. A Dictionary stores a lookup key, as the HashSet, but in addition, also a value. We will use the key for the word, and the value for a number that contains the amount of how often the word appeared in the first list.

```
Dictionary<string, int> temp1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var word in FirstFileWords)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (temp1.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        temp1[word]++;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1.Add(word, 1);
    }
}
```

Now a dictionary cannot be sorted, which complicates things at this point as you still need to get your sorting by word length done. So let's get back to your Array.Sort method which I think is a good choice when you are not allowed to use Linq:

```
KeyValuePair<string, int>[] firstFileWordsWithCount = temp1.ToArray();
Array.Sort(firstFileWordsWithCount, (x, y) => y.Key.Length.CompareTo(x.Key.Length));
```

**Note**: You are using `.ToArray()` in your example, so I think it's OK to use it. But strictly speaking, this would also fall unter using Linq IMHO.

Now all that's left is working through your `firstFileWordsWithCount` array until you got 10 words that do not exist in the HashSet `temp2`. Something like:

```
int foundWords = 0;

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> candidate in firstFileWordsWithCount)
{
    if (!temp2.Contains(candidate.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{candidate.Key}: {candidate.Value}");
        foundWords++;
    }

    if (foundWords >= 10)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If anything is unclear, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly I don't have time to run through it right now and test it for myself, but would it be possible for me to comment below this post again tomorrow and interact with you that way?

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot again, skimmed through it and it doesn't seem to be too complicated, but if anything comes up (and something probably will) - I'll ask, sorry in advance if I become annoying with beginner questions haha

Comment: I don't believe the IsNullOrEmpty is needed when using StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries during split. Or am I wrong there? Also I don't think the HashSet was needed, as you can take string out of the string array from file 2, and compare it directly to keys inside dictionary and remove it when it exists.

Comment: @Verkade89 If he uses RemoveEmptyEntries, he could omit the null check. Although I am hesitant to recommend to beginners to search for ways to avoid null/empty checks. However your implementation with removing items from the first dictionary is a way to avoid generating an additional List/HashSet, but the sort order is not guaranteed that way. See my comments below your post.

Comment: @BernhardKoenig Actually no questions, took a little bit to analyse what was happening exactly but fully understood it and it works perfectly :) Thanks a lot mate you're a lifesaver

Answer (score -1):

This is what you'll get when using dictionaries:

```
string File1 = "AMD Intel Skylake Processors Graphics Cards Nvidia Architecture Microprocessor Skylake SandyBridge KabyLake";
string File2 = "Graphics Nvidia";
Dictionary<string, int> Dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string[] File1Array = File1.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Array.Sort(File1Array, (s1, s2) => s2.Length.CompareTo(s1.Length));
foreach (string s in File1Array)
{
    if (Dic.ContainsKey(s))
    {
        Dic[s]++;
    }
    else
    {
        Dic.Add(s, 1);
    }
}

string[] File2Array = File2.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in File2Array)
{
    if (Dic.ContainsKey(s))
    {
        Dic.Remove(s);
    }
}

int i = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Dic)
{
i++;
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value);
    if (i == 9)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

My earlier attempt was using LINQ, which is apparently not allowed but missed it.

```
string[] Results = File1.Split(" ".ToCharArray()).Except(File2.Split(" ".ToCharArray())).OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).Take(10).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < Results.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Results[i] + " " + Regex.Matches(File1, Results[i]).Count);
}
```

Comment: From question: `am not allowed to use linq`

Comment: @L.B Ah sorry, did not read that part. I will fix it soon with Dictionary. Doubt it be faster tho

Comment: @Verkade89 First, you forgot to increase `i` in your last `foreach` block. :) But more importantly, you rely on the insertion order in your Dictionary `Dict` - but this order is not guaranteed according to the documentation. You can't rely that the elements in `Dict` are in the same order as you have inserted them. If they are, this is a coincidence. So it won't work reliably that way. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (" The order in which the items are returned is undefined.").

Comment: @BernhardKoenig You're right there, I completely forget about it. I only got the right amount of words because I made myself a small sample with 11 words where I filter 2 out. Also in normal situations I also work with Skip and Take to take the right amount of items, so then usually there is no need for counter in foreach loop, and relying to break the loop with the counter. As for the dictionary order, I've heard it before that you can't really rely on it. I have yet to find a situation when it does not work tho... maybe when internal dictionary structure changes? I have to look more intothat

Comment: @Verkade89 The current implementation of Dictionary normally retains the insertion order as long as you don't start removing and adding things again, but still you can't rely on it as the documentation states clearly that items are not ordered in any way. It works in your very particular test case, but what if you insert thousands of words? It could easily happen that a rehashing is needed when the underlying storage for the dictionary needs to be extended. When you need to retain sort order, you must use something that guarantees that.

Comment: @Verkade89 If you want a simple example that shows you that Dictionary is not built for retaining insertion order: Create a Dictionary, add 5 items, remove item 3, then add another new item and print out the items in a foreach. You'll see that the last item will have obtained the former place of item 3. Compare that to a List, where the new item would still be inserted at the end of the list.

Comment: @BernhardKoenig Yeah, the extending and removing+adding is something I haven't tested. In my other test scenario, I created a new instance of (concurrent)dictionary from a IEnumerable result where I ordered some stuff. Even when adding millions of items to the dictionary, it seemed to work at keeping the order. It's something I've been experimenting with for personal use in combination with multithreading. It was either SortedDictionary + locks, or ConcurrentDictionary, and rebuild it every minute or so. Each has it pros and cons. Possible deadlock+Always up to date, or none of those.